# Why include `master` in the command `git fetch upstream master`?

Tags: git, github, git-fetch

In the section **Pulling in upstream changes** on [help.github's **Forking a project**](http://help.github.com/forking/) it states:

> Some time has passed, the upstream repo has changed and you want to update your fork before you submit a new patch. There are two ways to do this:

```
$ git fetch upstream master

$ git merge upstream/master
```

Why are they including `master` in the fetch command? I've looked at the `git help fetch` information but I'm not understanding what including `master` does. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That allows you to:

- update your local version of the master upstream branch only (as opposed as updating *all* branches of the upstream repo, which can be longer to do)
- no trigger a merge *right away* (as opposed to the pull command)

The `git merge` will then try to merge that local version of the upstream master to your repo master branch.

So here, master is, for the `fetch` command, a refspec.

```
<refspec>
```

> The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus +, followed by the source ref `<src>`, followed by a colon :, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.
>
> The remote ref that matches `<src>` is fetched, and if `<dst>` is not empty string, the local ref that matches it is fast-forwarded using `<src>`.
>   If the optional plus `+` is used, the local ref is updated even if it does not result in a fast-forward update.

Here, `<dst>` is empty, so the matching local branch (your master) is updated.

---

Without master, that would give:

```
git fetch upstream
```

> The above command copies all branches from the remote `refs/heads/` namespace and stores them to the local `refs/remotes/upstream/` namespace, unless the `branch.<name>.fetch` option is used to specify a non-default refspec.